# How to make one button aligned to the left side and one to the right?

Tags: html, css, button

I want to make it so that two buttons underneath each other are on the left side of the page, and another two buttons underneath each other, aligned with the other buttons, on the right side of the page. I tried using a `<table>` and I tried making two `<div>`s, one of them with  `style='align-items: left;'` and one with `style='align-items: right;'` and this didn't work. Is there a solution?

Comment: You are probably on the right track with using flexbox, but you should check out [the documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/CSS_layout/Flexbox) to make sure you are using it correctly. Otherwise, if you want more help and better answers, please include a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) of your existing code, and perhaps an image that illustrates what UI you are trying to create.

Comment: Kindly show the code for clarity, since it's hard to give any solution without a proper understanding. As far as I can understand you want to align two buttons to the left and right sides of the screen. Have you tried `flex-box`. In any case, I have answered the question with an example.

Answer (score 1):

#### Use Flexbox (`display: flex`) rather than a table, to achieve this

Create an outer `div`, which we will call the "container", and two inner `div`s, each of which will have a vertical column of two buttons.

The container `div`, we  need to instruct to:

- be a flexbox
- be arranged as a row of items (i.e. side by side)
- put all unused space in between the items

This will put the items at the far left and far right.

Each of the two columns can then be a flex-box too, but you want them arranged vertically, i.e. `column` format.

```css
.flex-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.flex-column {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
```

```html
<div class="flex-container">

  <div class="flex-column">
    <button>One</button>
    <button>Two</button>
  </div>

  <div class="flex-column">
    <button>Three</button>
    <button>Four</button>
  </div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this could be a useful sample:

```css
.container{
display: flex;
justify-content: space-between;
}
.left, .right{
display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="left">
      <button> Left 1 </button>
      <button> Left 2 </button>
    </div>
    <div class="right">
      <button> Right 1 </button>
      <button> Right 2 </button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here I used flexbox to align two buttons to the left and right side of the screen

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Test</title>
    <style>
        div{
            display: flex;
            justify-content: space-between;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div>
        <button>Button1</button>
        <button>Button2</button>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

First, you change the display of the parent element to `display: flex;`
and then `justify-content: space-between;`